# Add quotes to every single entry of a list

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, quotes

I have a list that goes like

```
Foo 6
Bar 9
Ding 8
Dong 7
...
```

I used some online tool to add commas to each entry, but if I try to create a list in python, i get a syntax error

```
list=[Foo 6, Bar 9, Ding 8, Dong 7,...]
```

I assume this is because i have strings and integers mixed, so adding quotes does work

```
list=["Foo 6, Bar 9, Ding 8, Dong 7,..."]
```

But this has only one entry, so its useless. Is there any way to convert this into

```
list=["Foo 6", "Bar 9", "Ding 8", "Dong 7",...]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: 1- do not use `list` as variable name, this is a python builtin. 2- what is the initial input? a text file? this is certainly not a python list

Comment: `l = ["Foo 6, Bar 9, Ding 8, Dong 7, ..."] ; l[0].split(', ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use below when i need to create a list from a table copied values

```
string = """Foo 6
Bar 9
Ding 8
Dong 7"""

for i in string.split("\n"):
    print(f"\"{i.strip()}\"", end=",")
```

Now the output is

```
"Foo 6","Bar 9","Ding 8","Dong 7",
```

Just Copy and paste to variable

After reading comment if you want a list variable you can run below

```
string = '''Foo 6
Bar 9
Ding 8
Dong 7'''

lis = []
for i in string.split("\n"):
    lis.append(i.strip())

print(lis)
```

Comment: this is not creating a list, but printing strings

Comment: Yes you can just copy the string that is being printed and assign to a variable

Comment: This is impractical, just generate a list

Comment: Added the required code

Answer (score 0):

You manage this input by separating the element with "," using split().

```
l = ["Foo 6, Bar 9, Ding 8, Dong 7"]

new_list = [ele.strip() for ele in l[0].split(",")]
```

Output:

```
['Foo 6', 'Bar 9', 'Ding 8', 'Dong 7']
```

Comment: The output has undesirable leading spaces.